# How to get value from form control with input value={{...}}

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I am getting a value from data table in input form to update data table. problem is when click edit value as show in input but click submit value not pass to formbuilder in ts file

html.

```
 <form [formGroup]="updateForm">
    <mat-form-field>
       <input matInput type="number" formControlName="quota" placeholder="Quota" min="1" value="{{rowData.quota}}">
    </mat-form-field>
 </form>

 <button type="submit (click)="updateConfirm(updateForm.get('quota').value)">Submit</button>
```

ts.

```
constructor(...){
   this.updateForm = this.formbuilder.group({
      quota: [''],
    });
}

updateConfirm(quota) {
   console.log(quota);
}
```

When click edit but not change value

```
value show ="1234" 
result is {quota: ""}
```

When click edit but change value. value is change

```
value show ="1234" change to "4567"
result is {quota: "4567"}
```

Comment: Did you follow the *angular.io* tutorial?

Comment: please read the official angular documentation. You are  using the reactive form in the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

Use [PatchValue](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#patching-the-model-value) to update the values in forms.

**Example**

```
this.updateForm.patchValue({
quota: 4567
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Use [set value](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setvalue) function instead of using value in your ts file

```
this.updateForm.controls['quota'].setValue(this.rowData.quota);
```

Answer (score 0):

this.updateForm.get('quota').setValue(value)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For an answer to work well, it is a good idea to explain why your answer works, not just to present some code.